# Google map integration in android not showing map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a issue in google map integration for android,
When i create a map activity and then integrate to google api getting gray background, but when i create a new project and then integrate new project to google map that will work perfectly, 
My actual project can't integrate to google map, can anyone help me,
i mean the issue in the map key how solve it.

```
public class MapViewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

}
```

This is the code of my `mapactivity`.

Comment: There is  a properties file in your Android project where you specify your API key.  Did you configure this file?  Also, you need to enable Maps for Android from the Google developers console.  Did you do that?

Comment: Yes i have enabled it

Comment: @SharafudheenKannath - did you get chance to check my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API key is set property in [gradle.properties](https://github.com/gosaliajigar/CSC519/blob/master/CSC519_HW4_89753/gradle.properties).

This key is retrieved in [build.gradle](https://github.com/gosaliajigar/CSC519/blob/master/CSC519_HW4_89753/app/build.gradle).

Here is exact implementation of [Google Map integration](https://github.com/gosaliajigar/CSC519/blob/master/CSC519_HW4_89753/app/src/main/java/edu/itu/csc519/csc519_hw4_89753/MapsMarkerActivity.java) with app.

Complete app and its code with screenshots is accessible [github](https://github.com/gosaliajigar/CSC519/tree/master/CSC519_HW4_89753).

`Note:` In MapsMarkerActivity's `onCreate`, I do use Geocoder which populates the longitude and latitude for the given city or default city.